# Convert ExpandoObject String Property to DateTime using Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper, expandoobject

I want to use Automapper to convert an ExpandoObject to a standard object.  The problem is several of the properties need to be converted from strings to DateTime, where the DateTime strings are non-standard.

Here is some sample code:

```cs
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic src = new ExpandoObject();
        src.Name = "Joe";
        src.MyDateTime = "0619201359";  //mmddyyhhmm format
        src.MyDate = "121515";          //mmddyy format

        src.testDate = DateTime.Today;

        var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<string, DateTime>().ConvertUsing(new MyDateTimeConverter()); 
        });
        configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

        var mapper = configuration.CreateMapper();

        Destination des = mapper.Map<Destination>(src);

        Console.WriteLine($"Name : {des.Name}");
        Console.WriteLine($"MyDate: {des.MyDate}");
        Console.WriteLine($"MyDateType {des.MyDateTime}");
    }
}

public class MyDateTimeConverter : ITypeConverter<string, DateTime>
{
    public DateTime Convert(string date, DateTime destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var dateFormat = date.Length switch
        {
            6 => "MMddyy",
            10 => "MMddyyHHmm",
            _ => throw new NotImplementedException($"Date format of {date} not implemented.")
        };

        return DateTime.ParseExact(date, dateFormat, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
    }
}

public class Destination
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime MyDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime MyDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

When I run this code, I get this error:

```
Unhandled exception. AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
Object -> Destination
System.Object -> Destination
 ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Func`4[System.Object,System.Object,AutoMapper.ResolutionContext,System.DateTime]' to type 'System.Func`4[System.Object,System.Object,AutoMapper.ResolutionContext,System.Object]'.
   at AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration.GetExecutionPlan[TSource,TDestination](MapRequest mapRequest)
   at AutoMapper.Mapper.MapCore[TSource,TDestination](TSource source, TDestination destination, ResolutionContext context, Type sourceType, Type destinationType, IMemberMap memberMap)
   at AutoMapper.Mapper.AutoMapper.IInternalRuntimeMapper.Map[TSource,TDestination](TSource source, TDestination destination, ResolutionContext context, Type sourceType, Type destinationType, IMemberMap memberMap)
   at AutoMapper.ResolutionContext.Map(Object source, Object destination, Type sourceType, Type destinationType, IMemberMap memberMap)
   at AutoMapper.Internal.ReflectionHelper.MapMember(ResolutionContext context, MemberInfo member, Object value, Object destination)
   at AutoMapper.Mappers.FromStringDictionaryMapper.Map[TDestination](IDictionary`2 source, TDestination destination, ResolutionContext context, ProfileMap profileMap)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Destination , ResolutionContext )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Destination , ResolutionContext )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Bruce\source\repos\SandBox\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 35
```

I assume that the problem in setting up MapperConfiguration. I have tried a number of different ways of configuring the ITypeConverter - to no avail.  From my research, I understand ExpandoObjects conversions are built-in to Automapper; therefore, you can not create a cfg.CreateMap between the ExpandoObject and destination object.

I'm lost on what to do.  Does anyone have an thoughts on how to accomplish this?  Thank you for any help.

Comment: Try the [MyGet](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/The-MyGet-build.html) build.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu That seemed to fix it.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Declare a class `Foo` -

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string MyDate { get; set; }
    public string MyDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Add an extra mapping configuration -

```cs
cfg.CreateMap<Foo, Destination>();
```

Now, first map from `ExpandoObject` to `Foo`, then from `Foo` to `Destination` -

```cs
Foo foo = mapper.Map<Foo>(src);
Destination destination = mapper.Map<Destination>(foo);
```

Comment: Thank you @atiyar. This certainly would work, but am hoping there is a way to have Automapper do this directly.  I have a number of different mapping that I need to do this for and would hate to add all these extra classes to the project.